# Update SAS code .sas file to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sas

I am a developer for a SharePoint 2010 site.  The users want to store SAS code from SAS 9.3 in SharePoint.  They will not use SAS Enterprise.

I can write (new add) from SAS 9.3 TS Level 1M0 to a SharePoint folder but it will not allow me to update (save changes) to the folder.  The only error I see at the lower left corner of sas is: ERROR: Save FAILED.  The Log does not show any action.  It works fine from SAS Enterprise but as I said they won't use it.

Has anyone encountered this problem?  If so, what did you do?  I have searched all over the internet and not seen this particular problem.  Lot of comments about saving output but nothing about saving .sas code.

Thanks

Liz

Comment: How are you currently trying to do this?  Do you have a folder mapped to a sharepoint location, and selecting 'save' from the dropdown menu?  Would it be acceptable to use a SAS program to write the other programs out to the location rather than using the GUI?

Comment: Joe,  I have a mapped drive to the SP location and I select 'save as' from the file tab.  I am not a SAS programmer.  I would love to try your suggestion but don't know how.  I did think of this earlier but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I imagine this might be related to the same reason we can't directly use programs on our CIS archive; something about the server that manages it doesn't play well with SAS (speed of access perhaps?) such that we have to move any files to a local drive or a normal NAS location first before using them or saving to them.  This despite other windows programs can access them with no difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and contacted SAS.  The problem relates to the name that the SAS Enhanced Editor uses when saving the file - there are characters that Sharepoint does not like (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231).

The workaround in SAS 9.3 is to use the older Program Editor by opening BASE SAS and selecting View > Program Editor and then try and saving a program from there.  However, the issue HAS been resolved in SAS 9.4 so the Enhanced Editor will save files OK on SharePoint with the newer software.